# Database mysql process overloading after cloning

Tags: mysql, wordpress, migration, clone

I clone my Wordpress site. I hosted them both in shared hosting. But now my new website always make overloading the sharedhosting server due to database mysql process.
Here are some screenshots:
https://prnt.sc/26lotyb
https://prnt.sc/26loucm

This is what I did to clone my site:

- Export database from phpmyadmin
- Compress and download files in public_html
- Upload, extract files in public_html, import database, connect them.
- Run SQL command to replace domain name
- Use the plugin Better Search Replace to replace needed things.

Comment: Your first screenshot, the one showing `top` output, says your VM is using swap space. That means the machine's physical RAM is overcommitted. It also shows some long-running processes. I would not want my web site sharing a host machine with cryptomining. Your second screenshot shows the MySQL server waiting to deliver some resultsets to your WordPress / php process.  It's possible that happens because the WordPress / php process isn't getting the CPU it needs.  Consider contacting support at your shared hosting vendor.

Comment: Thank you very much!
My original site does not make these issues, but the cloned site make them. So I don't understand why do they work like that?